# How to use redirect_to method inside of custom class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This one is very straightforward. with my controllers, i am using special custom class stored in concerns. I would like this class to be able to send user, well, places. In order to do this i need path helpers, which i got with this:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

but this approach also requires `redirect_to` method. what module should i include inside my class to be able to use it? or maybe some class it can inherit after? (but module would much more elegent solution).

Comment: Why do you can't do it with a 'classic' controller? Then the controller calls the "services" methods of your custom class.

Comment: or place it in a helper module and call it when needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Rails 2.3](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/), the `redirect_to` that you want is a protected method in ActionController::Base, so you'd have to make a subclass of that class.  In [the most recent Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) (currently 4.0.2), it's a public method in ActionController::Redirecting, so you could include that module.

The commenters on the original question are right, though: it doesn't sound like a good idea to do a redirect from an object that's not really a controller.