# Rails redirect_to inside custom class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a custom Class in my Rails application, which validates a bunch of settings.

The code:

```
class UserSettingObject < RailsSettings::SettingObject
  validate do
    if !/^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0]):[0-5][0-9]$/.match(self.time)
      redirect_to settings_path, notice: 'Invalid time format'
    end
  end
end
```

I check SO posts and found a similar problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453638/how-to-use-redirect-to-method-inside-of-custom-class)), the recommendation was `include ActionController::Redirecting` but it doesn't works, resulting in undefined method `config_accessor' error.

How to use Rails redirects methods in a custom Class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what @SergioTulentsev already said, validations are for validating, not for taking actions. What you could do instead is leaving the regexp as a method, and in controller check the `time` using it and redirect based on the result of the validation.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I just realized, that you actually answered a question, while I proposed an alternative to something, that is not working :) Upvoted

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is: you can't do that.

`redirect_to` only makes sense in request context (read: when being called from within controller action). You can't redirect from random objects, because they don't know what request to manipulate.

And yes, what @AndreyDeineko says.